# How can I hide the letters after a certain number character in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
ListTile(
    leading: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.qrcode,
            size: 50),
    title: Text(record.hes, style: (
                  TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30,
                    color: Color(0xFF545F61),
                  )
                ),),
    subtitle: Text(record.name + " " + record.sname, style: (
                  TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: Color(0xFF545F61),
                  )
                ),),
    onTap: () => print(record.tc),
  ),
```

I have a listTile like this. When I show names and surnames I want to hide after first 2 character. Like name: "mi**" and sname: "ly***" for name:"mike" and sname:"lynch"
Note: I take this records from firebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try this

```
record.name.replaceRange(2, record.name.length, "*" * (record.name.length - 2))
// or 
record.sname.replaceRange(2, record.sname.length, "*" * (record.sname.length - 2))
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
int visibleCharacters = 2;

var hiddenName = record.name.substring(0, visibleCharacters) + 
                ('*' * (record.name.length - visibleCharacters));

var hiddenSurname = record.sname.substring(0, visibleCharacters) +
                  ('*' * (record.sname.length - visibleCharacters));
```